# polyglot - TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, function, polyglot

I'm trying to use polyglot nlp package to run sentiment analysis, where I define

```
    def sentiment(text):
            senti = Text(text)
            pol = senti.polarity
            return senti, pol

sentiment("beautiful moon")
returns

    (Text("beautiful moon"), 1.0)
```

but when I implement the function into a pandas df

```
text["sentiment"] = text["word"].apply(sentiment)
```

results into error:

```
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

how to fix this function issue? thank you.

Comment: Does `agg` work instead of `apply`?

Comment: Show us how `text` is created.

Comment: @HenryEcker it also returns ``TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable``

Comment: @JohnGordon Text is a class object from polyglot ``polyglot.text.Text``

Comment: I asked about the variable `text` in the above code, not `Text`.  It looks like you expect `text` is a dictionary, but the error says it is a function.  So I wanted to see how that variable is created.

Comment: @JohnGordon ``text`` is a pandas dataframe and ``word`` is a column containing rows of sentences

Comment: The error message says that `text` is a function.  Double-check that you don't have a function named that.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you. Text was indeed being identified as ``function`` while Text is a ``class``. After having treated Text as class and updated the variable name text, the function works perfectly